# global variables in templates

Tags: templates, single, globals

I have defined a global variable in one of my template files `page.php`. I can access the global variables in my loop. But when the loop displays an individual post in `single.php`, the variable has no value. I defined the variable as global in my `single.php`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Define it in `functions.php`, which is loaded on every request.

However, there are far better options than a global variable:

- a function
- a template part if it's a template you're defining
- filters

Comment: I did define it in functions and I'm still not getting it.

Comment: @LindaH53 I'd strongly recommend against global variables, but remember that you have to tell PHP in a file that the variable is global, e.g. `global $variable;`, and if you don't PHP won't use the global variable.

Comment: OK, thanks. I am putting it into a function. What's the reason for discouraging global variables? Thanks.

Comment: global state is an anti-pattern, and with global variables it's easy to accidentally overwrite other global variables from other code, or forget the `global` keyword. It also makes writing unit tests near impossible as the global variables provide hidden state the tests can't control